# Netbeans 7.3 Rails 4.00 bundle

Tags: ruby, netbeans, bundle

Can I run the following command from within Netbeans for a ruby project without going to terminal?

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/xxxx_xxxx_spec.rb
```